# OneSignal push notification | disable them for a chat when in the chat | Android

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, chat, onesignal

I'm building a **One-to-one chat app** in Android.
Everything is working fine but I wonder how I can do to avoid receiving notifications for a conversation when this conversation is open.

Example:
I'm speaking with **B** and **B** sends me a message, I see the message in the chat view BUT I also receive the notification telling me B sent you a message.

How can I avoid that? I can't think of a working and efficient solution.

Comment: And how are you showing notification?

Comment: Without a backend, I doubt there is a solution. If you have a backend, you could send something like "idChat" to the device, and if the idChat received in notification is the same as the idChat you are in, prevent showing the notification in your NotificationExtenderService

Answer (score 1):

You can use this handler to decide if the notification should show or not

```
class NotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler : OneSignal.OSNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler {

    override fun notificationWillShowInForeground(notificationReceivedEvent: OSNotificationReceivedEvent?) {
        when (isHideInForeground) {
            true -> {
                notificationReceivedEvent?.complete(null)
            }
            else -> {
                notificationReceivedEvent?.complete(notificationReceivedEvent.notification)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initialization

```
OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(NotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler())
```